# Why is CORS blocking angular requests in .NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

I am getting a CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:5000/api/MessageBroadcast/GetByDate' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. [http://localhost:4200/]

When calling my .NetCore web api from Angular

I have set up cors in the app:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddCors();

}


// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseHsts();
  }

  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseCors(
      options => options.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials()
  );


  app.UseMvc();
}
```

Despite it being set up it is not recognizing the call and continues to give the error.

I have tested in postman to verify that to api returns the correct data.

UPDATE

Per comment request I changed this code:

```
 app.UseCors(
      options => options.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowCredentials()
  );
```

I am still getting the issue

UPDATE 2

I also attempted to add the Enable Cors Attribute to the individual methods just in case:

```
 [EnableCors]
```

UPDATE 3

I swapped the order of the following two registrations:

```
  app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());

  app.UseMvc();
```

This slightly fixed the issue.

> net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

When I commented out the :

```
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

The app works correctly now. Obviously I would much prefer the ability to use HTTPS.

Comment: You need to set up CORS in the API.

Comment: @SLaks I have set it up in the API i posted above where I did all of the set up

Comment: I think it was that "allow credentials" is not compatible with "allow any origin". Try adding your angular site hostname as an allowed origin and remove the AllowAnyOrigin

Comment: @juunas So I need to add the url through the WithOrigins method?

Comment: Yeah that's correct :)

Comment: @juunas I updated that and its still giving the same error

Comment: Okay.. Well it was worth a try. Can you see the OPTIONS request in the browser dev tools? What happens to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189978/discussion-between-robert-and-juunas).